# How can I remove the border from a React table?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-table

I am using React Table for building Table in React JS. (https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table). I can’t find how remove border in React Table. Please help me, thank you.

```
const tableStyle = {
  border: "none",
  boxShadow: "none"
};

class App extends React.Component{

  render(){
    const columns = [{
      Header: "Id",
      accessor: "id",
      headerClassName: 'headerTable',
      className: 'firstColumn',
    },
    {
      Header: "Name",
      accessor: "name",
      headerClassName: 'headerTable',
    },
    {
      Header: "Username",
      accessor: "username",
      headerClassName: 'headerTable',
    },
    {
      Header: "Email",
      accessor: "email",
      headerClassName: 'headerTable',
    }]

    return(
      <div>
        <ReactTable
        style={tableStyle}
        data = {this.state.users}
        columns = {columns}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

table.css

```
.headerTable{
  background-color: #e8edf2;
  padding: 100px 0px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #1c2229;
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

This is my Table:

[image: image1]

Comment: Override class and set `border: none`

Answer (score 1):

Here is and example taken from this [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-simple-table-k3824).

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { makeData, Logo, Tips } from "./Utils";

// Import React Table
import ReactTable from "react-table";
import "react-table/react-table.css";

const tableStyle = {
  border: "none",
  boxShadow: "none"
};

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: makeData()
    };
  }
  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <ReactTable
          style={tableStyle}
          data={data}
          columns={[
            {
              Header: "First Name",
              accessor: "firstName",
              className: "sticky",
              headerClassName: "sticky"
            },
            {
              Header: "Last Name",
              id: "lastName",
              accessor: d => d.lastName
            },
            {
              Header: "Age",
              accessor: "age"
            },
            {
              Header: "Age",
              accessor: "age"
            },
            {
              Header: "Age",
              accessor: "age"
            },
            {
              Header: "Age",
              accessor: "age"
            },
            {
              Header: "Age",
              accessor: "age"
            },
            {
              Header: "Age",
              accessor: "age"
            },
            {
              Header: "Age",
              accessor: "age"
            },
            {
              Header: "Status",
              accessor: "status"
            },
            {
              Header: "Visits",
              accessor: "visits"
            }
          ]}
          defaultPageSize={10}
          className="-striped -highlight"
        />
        <br />
        <Tips />
        <Logo />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

As you can see I defined an object called `tableStyle` that contains css properties and I passed it to the component `ReactTable` using the style prop

Comment: Yep sorry, I have 2 questions, which border do you want to remove? And which rules are you definining for the className `headerTable`?

Comment: The entire table include header and body table want to remove. headerTable is style for Header table. I already put the code in my question for CSS.

Comment: Is the screenshot of the table updated? If not can you please send a screenshot of the table with the border property set as `none`? If you've already updated it and results is the same I think this is all you can do (even if it is really weird, because on code sandbox it works). Another thing you can try is set border as `solid 2px` and see the result and the try with `solid 0px` (the same as none).

Comment: hey I used borderd={false} and rowStyle={border:'0px'} it removed the borders of rows but I am unable to remove borders of columns how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom className prop to the Table and style it directly through css or add a style prop and add some inline styles. You can check out this section about styling and custom props section bellow this:
https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/v6#styles

Answer (score -1):

You can use the property `getTdProps`

```
 getTdProps={() => ({
    style: { border: `none` },
  })}
```